# WP7 : How to do some treatment during splash screen, but before the first page is open?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In a Windows Phone 7 application, I need to do some treatment before the first page gets opened.
But I'd like to do it during the splash screen, so the user knows the application is effectively running.

I tried several events :

- **Application.Launching** event is fired before splash screen
- **Frame.Navigated** event is fired after the first page is loaded

Is there any way to do something between those 2 events ?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using the technique outlined in this blog post ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/17/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications.aspx

Comment: This technique is a nice workaround, but it involves creating a "dummy" page to do some work, and then navigate to the actual first page. (the backgroundWorker_DoWork method is executed **after** the first page has been loaded)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone 7 application execution model allows you to perform various operations when the application is loading (as you mentioned - before the actual splash screen) and after the application is loaded (add **activated** and **deactivated** to that list as well). You cannot insert specific processes between application loading and loading completion - only on initialization and after it.

For more information, I'd recommend reading:

[Understanding the Windows Phone Application Execution Model, Tombstoning, Launcher and Choosers, and Few More Things That Are on the Way – Part 1](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx)

Going further, it is not recommended to perform time and resource-consuming operations while the application is launching. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

> Applications should not load state
>   data from Isolated Storage in the
>   handler for this event. Because this
>   event is raised before the application
>   is visible or active, performing time
>   consuming tasks, like accessing
>   Isolated Storage can provide a bad
>   user experience as the application
>   will take a long time to load.
>   Instead, calls to Isolated Storage and
>   network resources should be performed
>   asynchronously after the application
>   has loaded.

It is not a restriction, but rather a recommendation that helps providing a better user experience. Therefore, you should carefully plan what you want to do on application startup.